# Show/hide title unreliable in FancyBox 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Trying to achieve consistent behavior of displaying title helper in Fancybox 2.
I'd like title be displayed when mouse pointer is over a fancybox window (inside `div.fancybox-wrap` element) - just and only.

Tried to use following code from user JFK's [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KTdDk/) :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  helpers: {
    title: {
      type: 'over'
    }
  },
  afterShow: function () {
    $(".fancybox-title").hide();
    // shows/hides title on hover
    $(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function () {
      $(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
    }, function () {
      $(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
    });
    // detects if mouse is already hover
    $(".fancybox-outer a, .fancybox-outer img").hover(function () {
      $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
        $(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
      }, 100));
    }, function () {
      clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    });
  }
});
```

However the above example does not work in Chromium browser. When mouse pointer is at the side of an image (left or right) and click used to display previous or next in the gallery, title is hidden on the new one - until pointer is moved a bit.

Any idea how to get it work in Chrome/Chromium also ? It's ok in Firefox.

**Update:** Title remains hidden also when next/previous image is invoked with cursor keys whereas mouse pointer is still inside `.fancybox-wrap`. Also fails to work in Chrome/Chromium.

**Update 2:** I can simulate the required behavior hooking not hover but *mouseover* event, however it has the known unpleasant side effect it gets triggered at entering/leaving each inner element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could track the mouse position and then use that to determine whether the mouse is currently hovering - this doesn't require the hover event to fire (which apparently it doesn't if the mouse doesn't move).

```
var lastMouseX,
    lastMouseY;

$(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
    lastMouseX = e.pageX;
    lastMouseY = e.pageY;
});

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        $(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function () {
            $(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideDown(200);

        }, function () {
            $(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
        });

        var fancyBoxWrap = $(".fancybox-wrap");
        var divTop = fancyBoxWrap.offset().top;
        var divLeft = fancyBoxWrap.offset().left;
        var divRight = divLeft + fancyBoxWrap.width();
        var divBottom = divTop + fancyBoxWrap.height();

        var currentlyHovering = lastMouseX >= divLeft && lastMouseX <= divRight &&
                                lastMouseY >= divTop && lastMouseY <= divBottom;

        if (currentlyHovering ) {
            $(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
        } else {
            $(".fancybox-title").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/8m4FD/

Comment: +1 : I have to admit it. Your answer is far better than mine. I wasn't happy using `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` nor sniffing the browser type (IE) I hope the OP will grant you the bounty ;)

Comment: I would just suggest to also bind the `.ready()` method to the `document` http://jsfiddle.net/ueS3V/

Comment: Although a workaround I like the simple solutions (not simpler) the most. You've got the bounty and my upvote ! Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some tweaks to the original answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14186766/1055987).

There were basically two issues :

1). This line (in the `afterShow` callback):

```
$(".fancybox-title").hide();
```

was always triggering first inside the `afterShow` callback regardless the mouse was `hover` or not. The workaround is to validate if the mouse is `hovering` the fancybox container before deciding to *hide* the `title` or not :

```
if ( !$('.fancybox-wrap:hover').length ) {
    // mouse is not hover
    $(".fancybox-title").hide();
}
```

However, the `:hover` pseudo class doesn't seem to work in IE8 and lower versions. Since we do care about cross-browser compatibility, we need an extra workaround for those browsers so we will add this variable

```
var isIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6-8]/i);
```

and validate for all browsers :

```
if ( !isIE ) {
    if ( !$(".fancybox-wrap:hover").length ) {
        // mouse is not hover
        $(".fancybox-title").hide();
    }
} else {
    $(".fancybox-title").hide();
    $(".fancybox-wrap").wrap("<a id='fancyhover' class='fancyhover' />");
}
```

**Notice** that we added the element `#fancyhover.fancyhover` (wrapping the fancybox wrapper) so we can play the toggling classes workaround for IE8-

2). I was validating the mouse `hover` state within a second `.hover()` method, which it was redundant (and buggy and confusing) so I moved the `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` functions within the first `.hover()` method used to show/hide the `title` on mouse `hover`.

Here is the full code (I have decided to leave the original code commented out for documentation purposes) :

```
var isIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6-8]/i);
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: "over"
            }
        },
        afterShow: function () {
            if ( !isIE ) {
                if ( !$(".fancybox-wrap:hover").length ) {
                    // mouse is not hover
                    $(".fancybox-title").hide();
                }
            } else {
                $(".fancybox-title").hide();
                $(".fancybox-wrap").wrap("<a id='fancyhover' class='fancyhover' />");
            }
            // shows/hides title on hover
            $(".fancybox-wrap").hover(function () {
                //$(".fancybox-title").stop(true,true).slideDown(200);            
                if ( isIE ) {
                    $("#fancyhover").toggleClass("fancyhover");
                    if ( !$("#fancyhover").hasClass("fancyhover") ) {
                        $(".fancybox-title").hide();
                    }
                }
                var $fancyWrap = $(this),
                    $fancyTitle = $fancyWrap.find(".fancybox-title");
                $fancyWrap.data("timeout", setTimeout(function () {
                    $fancyTitle.stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
                }, 200));
            }, function () {
                //$(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
                clearTimeout($(this).data("timeout"));
                $(this).find(".fancybox-title")
                    .stop(true, true)
                    .slideUp(100);
            });
            /*
        // detects if mouse is already hover
        $(".fancybox-outer a, .fancybox-outer img").hover(function () {
            $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
                $(".fancybox-title").stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
            }, 100));
        }, function () {
            clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
        });
        */
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[new JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9huY8/)**

Now you can navigate through the gallery using either, the fancybox navigation arrows (on click) or the keyboard arrows. The `title` will show up if (and if only) the mouse's pointer is `hover` the fancybox.

It seems to work consistently in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari and (of course) IE.